# backbone.js block route execution

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Is it possible to block route execution in `backbone.js` using only the router?

I'm aware there is a callback method for each route where I could check if routing is allowed, I just don't see how I can block execution based on a property (canNavigate) on my viewmodel.

I also want this to work on url's that are not specified as route (`sammy.js` cannot do this, can backbone do this?). So for example:

When route `#/contact` is opened the active method on viewmodel '`contact`' is called.
When navigating away from `#/contact` to any other url like `#/page1`, `/page2` or `google.com`
I want the canNavigate method on the contact viewmodel to be called.
If this returns false, the routing to the urls should be blocked and a message should appear (I do not need the code to show a message etc, just the backbone.js code if possible).

Is this possible with `backbone.js`?
If not, which other framework (other then `sammy.js` since we tried this already) might do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with every framework if you write your Router extension. It takes probably less time, than asking this question. I don't know whether it is supported in backbone, or not, I'll check the code.

This is the method you are looking for:

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
  if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
  if (!callback) callback = this[name];
  Backbone.history.route(route, _.bind(function(fragment) {
    var args = this._extractParameters(route, fragment);
    callback && callback.apply(this, args);
    this.trigger.apply(this, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
    Backbone.history.trigger('route', this, name, args);
  }, this));
  return this;
},
```

As you see it is just running the callback, and does not block anything.

You can extend it for example this way:

```
var RouteError(message) {
    this.name = "RouteError";
    this.message = (message || "");
}
RouteError.prototype = Error.prototype;


var MyRouter = function (){
    Backbone.Router.apply(this, arguments);
};
MyRouter.prototype = Object.create(Backbone.Router.prototype);
MyRouter.prototype.constructor = MyRouter;
_.extend(MyRouter.prototype, {
    route: function(route, name, callback) {
      if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
      if (!callback) callback = this[name];
      Backbone.history.route(route, _.bind(function(fragment) {
        var args = this._extractParameters(route, fragment);
        try {
            callback && callback.apply(this, args);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            if (e instanceof RouteError)
                return this;
            else
                throw e;
        }
        this.trigger.apply(this, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
        Backbone.history.trigger('route', this, name, args);
      }, this));
      return this;
    },
});
```

or this way:

```
var loadUrl = Backbone.History.prototype.loadUrl;
Backbone.History.prototype.loadUrl = function (fragmentOverride){
    try {
        loadUrl.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    catch (e){
        if (e instanceof RouteError)
            return ;
        else
            throw e;
    }

};
```

(I did not check any of these...)

So I don't think this is natively supported in the Backbone...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I fail to understand how this extended method would work with url's not configured as routes. Also, I think I would need to check if navigating is possible ont the new viewmodel callback for the route trying to execute if I implement this.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't fully understand your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Backbone the only way I found to check things before/after routing is extending Router.route. Doesn't feel very clean since you have to copy from source code and edit, but is the only way I found. Below Backbone default code (1.0.0) and between comments the custom code that you need:

```
  Backbone.Router.prototype.route = function(route, name, callback) {
    if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
    if (_.isFunction(name)) {
      callback = name;
      name = '';
    }
    if (!callback) callback = this[name];
    // here custom code
    callback = _.wrap(callback, _.bind(function(cb) {
      console.log('before');
      _.bind(cb, this)();
      console.log('after');
    }, this));
    // finish custom code
    var router = this;
    Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
      var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);
      callback && callback.apply(router, args);
      router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
      router.trigger('route', name, args);
      Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
    });
    return this;
  };
```

Notice `_.wrap` and `_.bind` so `this` is the one that you would expect when using the router. Otherwise I was getting a "this is undefined" error.

Now you can hook your checks before/after your routes fire. In the affected router you can load your view and do whatever actions you need.